# AWS S3 bucket policy for Get object, error in the policy generator Json code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I generated the below code using S3 policy generator, when I paste the code in AWS S3 edit policy console it shows error. Pls help

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1611491895768",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1611491893687",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-landing-zone-configuration-756692330110-ap-south-1",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "\"AWS\": \"arn:aws:iam::756692330110::user/aravindkumar.s@gmail.com\""
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You would typically assign the S3 permissions directly to this IAM user or add the IAM user to an IAM group and assign the S3 permissions to that group, rather than do this in the S3 bucket policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues,

- GetObject is applicable only to bucket objects not bucket , so, Resouce should contain `/*` at the end.
- Principle is not formatted right.

Here is updated policy

```
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1611491895768",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1611491893687",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::756692330110:user/aravindkumar.s@gmail.com"]
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-landing-zone-configuration-756692330110-ap-south-1/*"
        }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: You added a cross-account permission for a different AWS account, which is not appropriate here.

Comment: @Balu Vyamajala - Thanks Balu